# Count how many characters above an integer cutoff

Tags: c++, string, ascii

Is there a more efficient way in `C++` to count the number of characters in a `string` which their integer `ASCII` value is above a certain cutoff other than evaluating one `char` at a time in a loop over the entire `string`?

Comment: You mean other than `std::countif()`

Comment: Well, if you have a string, and you have to determine if every character in the string passes or fails to meet a certain requirement, you will need to figure out how to break some fundamental laws of physics of the universe we live in, in order to accomplish that without actually having to look at every character in the string.

Answer (score 3):

As drescherjm said, what you want is `std::count_if`. For example, find all the characters that have an ASCII value greater than that of '3':

```
 std::string s = "12345";
 const char value = '3';
 int count = std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), 
     [](const char& a) { return a > value; } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could parallelize (threads) or vectorize (SSE vector instructions) it I guess, though with optimizations maxed out, some compilers will vectorize a simple checking loop like this for you, so explicit vectorization wouldn't be needed.

The savings are likely to be tiny though; for a task this simple, either the string is small enough that optimizations don't help/matter, or you're likely to be memory bandwidth bound; the CPU can churn through a string like this pretty darn fast.

That said, there is no real reason to bother. [`std::countif`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) will make for simple code, so unless you've proved (through profiling) that the code is too slow, just use it:

```
int num_above_a = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](unsigned char c){return c > 'a';})
```